# Twitter Bootstrap not working in CodeIgniter website but working in fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

My Problem is that i cant get the twitter bootstrap to work in my website
whereas it works perfectly fine in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mns8q/32/

Can anyone tell me what is the problem.?
Thanks in advance.

This code is present in the view that is called when you reach the url in my website, which is same as the fiddle :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>

<style>
@import url('http://psestest.hubvents.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
 body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  .frame {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    .navbar .navbar-inner {
      border-radius: 0;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .menu {
      height:100%;
      /* background-color: #3D6AA2; */

      &.collapse {
        float:left;
        height: 100% !important;
        width: auto;
      }

      &.collapse.height {
        position: relative;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
        -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
        -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
        transition: height 0.35s ease;
      }

      &.collapse.width {
        position: relative;
        width: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease;
        -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease;
        -o-transition: width 0.35s ease;
        transition: width 0.35s ease;
      }

      &.collapse.in.width {
        width: auto;
      }

      &.collapse.in.height {
        height: auto;
      }

      .collapse-inner {
        position: relative;        
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .navbar .navbar-inner {
        text-align: center;
        color: grey;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 38px;
      }

      .nav-stacked {
        padding: 0 10px;
      }

    }
    .view {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;

      .navbar .navbar-inner .btn-navbar {
        display: block;
        float: left;
      }
      #contentm {
        margin: auto 15px;
        text-align: justify;
      }
    }
  }
}

</style>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
changeContent = function(key) {
  html = textHash[key];
  $('#contentm').html(html);
}

$("#menu a").click(function(e) {
  $('#menu').collapse('hide');
  changeContent(e.target.innerText);
});

textHash = {
  "Futurama": "<h1>Bendin' in the Wind</h1><p>Oh, but you can. But you may have to metaphorically make a deal with the devil.  And by \"devil\", I mean Robot Devil.  And by \"metaphorically\", I mean get your coat. Say what? Ok, we'll go deliver this crate like professionals, and then we'll go ride the bumper cars. Yep, I remember. They came in last at the Olympics, then retired to promote alcoholic beverages! Michelle, I don't regret this, but I both rue and lament it.</p>",
  "Star Wars": "<h1>The Empire Strikes Back</h1><p>Remember, a Jedi can feel the Force flowing through him. Look, I can take you as far as Anchorhead. You can get a transport there to Mos Eisley or wherever you're going. She must have hidden the plans in the escape pod. Send a detachment down to retrieve them, and see to it personally, Commander. There'll be no one to stop us this time!</p>",
  "Doctor Who": "<h1>The Poison Sky</h1><p>Stop talking, brain thinking. Hush. You hit me with a cricket bat. You've swallowed a planet! Stop talking, brain thinking. Hush. It's a fez. I wear a fez now. Fezes are cool. Annihilate? No. No violence. I won't stand for it. Not now, not ever, do you understand me?! I'm the Doctor, the Oncoming Storm - and you basically meant beat them in a football match, didn't you?</p>"
};
});
</script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="frame">
      <div id="menu" class="menu nav-collapse collapse width">
        <div class="collapse-inner">
          <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
              Menu

            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
            <li><a>Futurama</a></li>
            <li><a>Star Wars</a></li>
            <li><a>Doctor Who</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="view">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentm">
          Integer eu quam et lacus luctus molestie.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does, `i cant get the twitter bootstrap to work` mean? The scripts/styles aren't being loaded? A certain part of the functionality isn't working as expected? You may have to be more specific.

Comment: Are you using scss on your server? Your styles aren't being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are not using SCSS on your site, while you are on the jsfiddle.

You could re-write your CSS as follows:

```
@import url('http://psestest.hubvents.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frame {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.navbar .navbar-inner {
    border-radius: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.collapse-inner {
    position: relative;        
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar .navbar-inner {
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.nav-stacked {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.view {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar .navbar-inner .btn-navbar {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#contentm {
    margin: auto 15px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.menu {
    height:100%;
}

.collapse {
    float:left;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: auto;
}

.collapse.height {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
    transition: height 0.35s ease;
}

.collapse.width {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    transition: width 0.35s ease;
}

.collapse.in.width {
    width: auto;
}

.collapse.in.height {
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively i used this tool to convert scss to css :
http://cssconvert.mgwebsolutions.net  .It is working..